# rosmake error:no such option

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am recently learning

```
          http://wiki.ros.org/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM
```

My system is Ubuntu 12.04 and ros-libfreenect.

This is some error I don't know how to fix it:

```
           root@ubuntu:~# rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam
           Usage: rosmake [options] [PACKAGE]...

           rosmake: error: no such option: --rosdep-install
```

Could you help me to try it out?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101901/rosmake-error:no-such-option/) by [Battery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7016/battery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error says to you "no such option". On a web site (http://wiki.ros.org/rosmake), it describes that option --rosdep-install is avalable for electric and earlier.  I guess you use fuerte, groovy or hydro. So I think you should try next command, because a web site (http://wiki.ros.org/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM) describes  Compile our package.

```
rosmake rgbdslam
```

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0